# Tabbed view with 3rd view?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a tabbed app with two tabs and associated views (two views).  One view is a tableview.  When a cell is clicked, I'd like to display another view, which will be related to the cell contents.

This introduces a 3rd view that isn't accessed via the tabs.  How do I bring in the 3rd view?

I'm guessing drop another viewcontroller onto the story board?  But from there, how do I push the 3rd view into visibility upon tableview cell click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having one UITabBarController connected to two UIViewControllers, connect your UITabBarController to a UINavigationController and a UIViewController. Put your UITableView inside the UINavigationController as root view controller. When a user taps on a cell, just perform a segue to yet another UIViewController that you push onto the navigation controller's stack.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: No idea what's going on here.

Comment: ah - much better.  Let me try that.

Comment: I have the same setup now.  One issue is that Tab1 is gone from the bottom navigation.  I only see tab2.  How do I fix that?

Comment: CTRL-drag from the tab bar controller to your missing controller and let go, you should get some options to add it. Like this: http://timroadley.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/TabToSplit.png make sure you select relationships view controllers.

Comment: Great! Done.  Awesome explanation.

Comment: I've already accepted the answer because you have answered my question completely.  But I'd like to do one more related thing.  I have a button on the bottom tabbed view (bottom white one in screenshot).  When the button is clicked, I'd like tab1 to come back into view.  I tried adding a push segue but get a SIGABRT. Do you know how that can be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72892/discussion-between-bensarz-and-4thspace).